# what is the use of generic return type

Tags: java

Please refer the code below. Here in the below method, what exactly is the usage of these parameters`<K,V>` before the method return type?

```
<K, V> boolean
```

The detailed code below:

```
public class Util {
    // Generic static method
    public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }
}
```

And finall we invoke it as `boolean same = Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);` : Here what are we supposed to do with `<Integer, String>` ?

Answer (score 4):

They are a declaration of the generic type arguments used within the method.

In the same way that the `boolean` keyword before the method name says that the method returns a boolean value, these arguments say that the type arguments `K` and `V` are used within the method.

It might seem slightly redundant to have to list them at the start when they can be seen in the parameter list of the method as well, but see Jesper's comment below.

Comment: It's not redundant. If you would not specify the type parameters, then how would the compiler know if they were type parameters instead of concrete type names? (Just the fact that it's a single upper-case letter doesn't automatically make it a type parameter).

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it is used to declare generic types to define a generic method. At runtime, those types are going to be inferred basing on the method call. This enables to guarantee a certain type safety. In your example, we force p1 and p2 to be pairs of the same types.